# how to add menu to ios xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, menu

hi I tried many tutorials but nothing success. I need to add a menu to app that have already two pages:
1 when the user access the app a view appear to choose language, 
2 login view 
3 homepage where i want to appear the menu. and let the menu appear in all pages that can accessed from the homepage.
any body can help me ? i'm beginner at c#, and xamarin , and no knowledge in swift

Answer (score 0):

It would have been useful to have seen what you've researched or tried already, but that being said, it's likely that you'd benefit from reading this Xamarin developer guide on how to implement a UITabBar, or UITabBarController<sup>†</sup>.

Just to give you an idea of what this is, here's an image of a UITabBar referenced from the guide:

[image: UITabBar]

It provides a series of buttons along the bottom of the UIViewController that allows the user to switch between UIViewControllers. iOS does not have an existing control that is similar to UWP/Androids 'Hamburger' menu, **Apples preferred** approach is the UITabBar.

---

<sup>†</sup> [UITabBarController guide.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/creating_tabbed_applications/)

Comment: but if i have more than 3 tabs like 8 tabs how can it will fit in the bottom , so because of that i want t use a menu

Comment: Apples developer guidelines state you can have no more than 5 visible buttons on the tab bar, so the UITabBar provides you with a 'menu' button on the right hand side, that allows you to then select additional tabs.